# Find similar words in strings in a for loop with python

Tags: python, regex, sqlite

I'm working with tweets and after text processing , the code returns something like:

- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amaet vi
- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amaet
- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amaet via

So sqlite database identify these records as unique.
My question is how can I find if two strings contains 5 similar words then skip it? Should I change my regex code or add `if statement`?

My code:

```
        clean1 = re.sub(r"(?:@\S*|#\S*|http(?=.*://)\S*)", "", tweet.text)
        clean2 = re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t:])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", clean1)
        final = re.sub(r'^RT[\s]+', '', clean2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: does my answer solute your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think regex will help in this situation

You could do this to tell if two lines have 5 same words

```
str1 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amaet vi" 
str2 = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amaet"

count = 0 
str1_split = str1.split(" ")
for word in str2.split(" "):
    if word in str1_split:
        count += 1

print count
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method to count same words in two string:

```
a="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amaet vi"
b="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amaet"
count=0
for i,j in zip(a.split(),b.split()):
    if i==j:
        count+=1
print count
```

Output:

```
5
```